# Простые преобразования файлов pdf: объединение, конвертирование из jpg, сжатие jpg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf

Мне нужно склеить несколько pdf-ов и jpg-ов в один pdf ограниченного размера.
Как это можно сделать на Ubuntu (18.04)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Объединение pdf

Самое простое решение для объединения файлов ---  `pdfunite`.
Устанавливаем  `poppler-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Синтаксис команды простой:

```
pdfunite src1.pdf .. srcN.pdf  dest.pdf
```

Можно использовать звездочки при задании исходных файлов, тогда они склеятся в алфавитном порядке.
То есть если вам важен порядок, то либо задавайте исходные файлы списком, либо переименуйте так, чтобы алфавитный  порядок ставил файлы на нужные места.

#### 2. Объединение pdf и jpg. Конвертация jpg в pdf.

Увы, `pdfunite` склеивает только pdf-ы, а на другие форматы ругается.
Нам нужно конвертировать jpg в pdf.
Для этого [устанавливаем](http://softhelp.org.ua/?p=5809) `imagemagick`.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Вообще-то, можно сразу склеить все файлы в pdf таким же синтаксисом, как в  `pdfunite`.
Но у меня был сначала только один jpg (а потом прислали еще один), 
и я их конвертировала по одному. Запускаю команду конвертирования

```
convert file.jpg file.pdf
```

А она и не работает! Говорит

```
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `file.pdf' @ 
error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

[Оказывается](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert),
в команде  `convert` есть проблемы с безопасностью, особенно если она используется вместе с веб сервером. Поэтому начиная с Ubuntu версии 18 эту команду по умолчанию ограничивают. Ограничения записаны в файл `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`.
Поскольку у меня нет сервера, я этот файл просто убираю, точнее, переименую:

```
sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlsave
```

Если бы у меня бы был веб сервер, то мне надо было бы отредактировать этот файл и заменить строчку

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

на

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

Это разрешает `ImageMagick`-у чтение, и запись.

Теперь склеиваем все файлы в один pdf.

#### 3. Объединение pdf и сжатие jpg

Тут можно было бы и остановиться, но файл оказался слишком большой.
Проверяю размеры исходных файлов, например, командой `ls -lh`, и оказывается, что один из исходных файлов jpg имеет размер в несколько мега.
Значит, надо уменьшить его, но так, чтобы еще было что-то видно.

Тут можно опять использовать `convert` из пакета `imagemagick`.
Я попробовала несколько вариантов, предложенных в [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick):

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% file.jpg file2.jpg
```

и

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 85% -sampling-factor 4:2:0  file.jpg file3.jpg
```

и все они были очень нечеткие.

Тогда я решила поправить исходный файл в `Shotwell Viewer`.
Я сделала максимальный контраст, и там же при сохранении уменьшила резолюцию.
Результат меня устроил.

Теперь опять склеиваем pdf-ы.
При склеивании `convert`-ом

```
convert src1.pdf .. srcN.pdf  dest.pdf
```

он пишет много раз

```
**** Error: stream operator isn't terminated by valid EOL.
           Output may be incorrect.
```

Но потом создает нормальный читабельный pdf.

А вот команда `pdfunite` ничего плохого не сообщает, и создает pdf, который выглядит так же, и весит в 4(!) раза меньше.

Comment: Самая лучшая программа для работы с PDF — pdftk.